# PGP Encryption before generating a csv file

Tags: c#, encryption, pgp

I 'm generating a csv file and uploading in Azure Blob Storage however I have a requirement where I also need to encrypt using PGP encryption, I followed this tutorial "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457453/PGP-Encryption-with-Csharp" it seems tedious and secondly it is encrypting after the file is generated, I need to encrypt before generating and uploading in Azure Blob, could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Get your csv data (string) to a memory stream / byte array and then use Bouncy Castle encryption utilities to encrypt that data. after encryption you can write the stream / byte array to a file and upload  to azure.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ contains samples

Comment: thanks I did some changes however how to pass the public key in memory stream instead of FileStream?